# How to pass id to React Js path link?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create path for  component like this "/products?id=uniqueId" for my React Js Project. Unique id is taken from database and depends on which product was chosen. My code is

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-dawn-ufho9?file=/src/Home.js)

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Products from "./Products"
import Home from "./Home"

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
                <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/">
                        {" "}
                        <Home/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/products">
                        {" "}
                        <Products />
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const products = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Product 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Product 2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Product 3"
  }
];

export default function Home() {
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleProceed = (e) => {
    // console.log(id, "home");
    history.push("/products", { id });
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
      <div>
        {products.map((product) => {
          return (
            <button
              onClick={(e) => {
                setId(product.id);
              }}
            >
              {product.name}{" "}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleProceed} style={{ width: "250px" }}>
        {" "}
        Proceed
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Product.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Home() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { id } = location.state || { id: "none" };

  console.log(id);
  return (
    <div>
      <p> Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Idea is when user presses any button with product name in  < Home /> component, page should be redirected to < Product /> component and path should be "/products?id=uniqueId" where uniqueId = to product.id. I was able to pass product.id from < Home /> to < Product /> using useHistory() and useLocation(), but I don't know how to make path display selected id. For example if user clicks Product 1 button, path to < Product /> should be "/products?id=1", if Product 2 was chosen path should reflect that as "/products?id=2"  and so on.

Any help and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could use route params instead of query string values for this. Change route to `<Route exact path="/products/:id">`, update `id` retrieval in `Products` to `const { id } = useParams();` and update the `history.push` in `Home` to `history.push("/products/" + id);`

Comment: Agreed, making the product id part of the path versus the query string makes passing/accessing it a bit simpler and easier. If you are open to that I can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest making the product `id` part of the path versus placing it in the query string. As part of the path it requires almost nothing from your code to access whereas if you used the query string you would then need to parse the entire query string into a Map of key-value pairs.

1. Define your path to include an `id`

   ```
   <Route path="/products/:id">
     <Products />
   </Route>
   ```
2. On the products page use `useParams` react hook to access the `id` Route match param.

   ```
   const { id } = useParams();
   ```
3. Generate the path with `id` parameter

   ```
   const handleProceed = (e) => {
     history.push(generatePath("/products/:id", { id }));
   };
   ```

   or if you prefer it raw

   ```
   const handleProceed = (e) => {
     history.push(`/products/${id}`));
   };
   ```

I further suggest optimizing your routing by reordering your `Route` components to specify the more specific paths first. This allows you to avoid passing the `exact` prop to every route.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/products/:id">
      <Products />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-pass-id-to-react-js-path-link]

full demo code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  generatePath,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useHistory,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

const products = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Product 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Product 2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Product 3"
  }
];

const Products = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  console.log(id);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Id: {id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleProceed = (e) => {
    id && history.push(generatePath("/products/:id", { id }));
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
      <div>
        {products.map((product, i) => (
          <button
            key={i}
            onClick={(e) => {
              setId(product.id);
            }}
          >
            {product.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleProceed} style={{ width: "250px" }}>
        Proceed
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/products/:id">
            <Products />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### `react-router-dom@6` Compliant Version:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  generatePath,
  Routes,
  Route,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

const products = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Product 1"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Product 2"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Product 3"
  }
];

const Products = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  console.log(id);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>Id: {id}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleProceed = (e) => {
    id && navigate(generatePath("/products/:id", { id }));
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", alignItems: "center" }}
    >
      <div>
        {products.map((product, i) => (
          <button
            key={i}
            onClick={(e) => {
              setId(product.id);
            }}
          >
            {product.name}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleProceed} style={{ width: "250px" }}>
        Proceed
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/products/:id" element={<Products />} />
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```